# SQL Calculate percentages of column values based on name

Tags: sql

I have a SQL query that goes like this:

```
    SELECT name, SUM(weight) weight, product FROM table GROUP BY name, product;
```

Which gives me output like this:

```
    |name         weight     product  |
    |custA        100        trash    |
    |custA        300        recycling|
    |custB        50         trash    |
    |custB        450        recycling|
```

Now I want to calculate the percentage of weight based on the name but still separated by product. So instead the output would look like this:

```
    |name         weight     product  |
    |custA        .25        trash    |
    |custA        .75        recycling|
    |custB        .10        trash    |
    |custB        .90        recycling|
```

Is there any way I can accomplish this with a regular SQL query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [CTE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx) and [correlated subquery](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187638(v=sql.105).aspx)

```
WITH TotalWeight(name, product, weightsum) AS 
(
    SELECT name, product, sum([weight]) as weightsum
    FROM custdetails
    GROUP BY name, product
)

SELECT name, product, weightsum, (0.0+weightsum)/(select sum([weight]) from custdetails where name = T.name) as percentage
FROM TotalWeight T;
```

This gives the following result:

```
name    product     weightsum  percentage
custA   recycling   300        0.750000000000
custA   trash       100        0.250000000000
custB   recycling   450        0.900000000000
custB   trash        50        0.100000000000
```

Comment: Works great. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

try something like this:

```
select a.name, a.weight/b.weight, a.product
from (
    select name, sum(weight) as weight, product
    from table
    group by name, product
) as a
inner join (
    select name, sum(weight) as weight
    from table
    group by name
) as b
on (a.name = b.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT table.name, SUM(weight) / custWeightTable.custWeght as weight ,        product FROM table ,  (SELECT name, SUM (weight) as custWeight  FROM table GROUP BY name) custWeightTable WHERE table.name = custWeightTable.name GROUP BY table.name, table.product;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using window functions:

```
SELECT name, product, SUM(weight) as weight,
       SUM(weight) / SUM(SUM(weight)) OVER (PARTITION BY name) as ratio
FROM table
GROUP BY name, product;
```

Note that some databases do integer division.  So, if weight is an integer, you may need to convert to a decimal of some type:

```
SELECT name, product, SUM(weight) as weight,
       SUM(weight) / SUM(1.0*SUM(weight)) OVER (PARTITION BY name) as ratio
FROM table
GROUP BY name, product;
```